# Include a global variable value in onclick property

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am using javascript onclick attribute. How to use a global varibale in that?
Global variable in JS file:

```
var globalVar;
globalVar = "Some String";
```

Now i want to use the above string my jsp page:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction(globalVar)">Link</a>
```

But its just passing as string i.e., the parameter is just passing as globalVar as a string but not its value. Can any one tell me how to apply this global variable value inside the attribute?

Comment: if you just need to access `globalVar`, you can even access its value in `myFunction`. You don't need to pas it as argument. It is already available to every function

Answer (score 4):

you can use alternate way like this
in html

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">Link</a>
```

in javascript

```
<script>
        var globalVar='somestring';
        function myFunction(){
        console.log(globelVar);
        }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Global arguments can be referenced inside an `onclick` function.  Example:

```js
var test_value = 3;

function test(val){
  console.log(val);
}
```

```html
<a onclick="test(test_value)">TEST </a>
```

Comment: But for some reason if i pass teh way you have mentioned, it is printing as: test_value for me in my application :( @DerekBrown

Comment: @Stack you would need to post the code to debug that.  Seems like an issue related to your project more broadly.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap them in a function like myFunction1(), and change it to:

```
    <a href="#" onclick="myFunction1">Link</a>
    ....
    ....

    function myFunction1() {
          myFunction(globalVar);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this, a global variable is something which is declared in a page, outsite of a javascript function ,and is fully accessible any where in that page. So for that,  declare the variable outside of the function and call it from anywhere.like

```
<script>var globalVar = "global Variable";
 function(){
 ////
}
</script>
```

call variable as,

```
<script>function myFunction(){
   console.log(globalVar );
  }</script>
```

Hope this will help.Thanks.